# how to create this type of layout in android using recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout

is it possible to create this layout using single RecyclerView GridLayoutManager? [image: click to see image]Each category is horizontally scrollable.Do i need to use multiple recyclerviews for each category?

Comment: Yes,you have to use multiple recycler view for each category

Comment: Check this https://github.com/yqritc/RecyclerView-MultipleViewTypesAdapter